# Can I separate the distance cubed in terms of the components themselves?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I was dealing with a distance squared between point i and j ($\theta_{ij}^2$).
Using the cosine law I managed to separate this into compontents that only included $\theta_i$, $\theta_j$ and the angle:

$\theta_{ij}^2 =  \theta_i^2 + \theta_j^2 - 2\theta_i\theta_jcos(\phi_{ij})$

Now I have to deal with a $\theta_{ij}^3$ and I was hoping I could use a similar law to simplify this in terms of $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ again.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can write $\theta_{ij}^3= ( \theta_i^2 + \theta_j^2 - 2\theta_i\theta_jcos(\phi_{ij}))^{3/2}$  I don't know if that helps, but I think it is the best you will do.